# Linear independence and span

Tags: linear-algebra, span

I need to know find all values of the parameter $t$, such that vectors $v, u, w$ span $\Bbb{R}^3$

$u= (1,1,1)$
$v=(1,5t,1)$
$w= (1,1, 25t^2)$

b) for which parameter $t$ is the set linearly independent?

c) for which parameter $t$ is the set dependent

I reached  $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\0&5t-1&0&0\\0&0&25t^2&0\end{pmatrix}$$
 and I am not sure if $t\neq \pm \frac15$ is a solution   to the question regarding span and independence.. and if they are dependent in $ t= \pm \frac15$.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Don't you even bother to ask the OP what has she done to solve the exercise?

@Anna, welcome to math.stackexchange, don't take the downvotes personal. In this forum there are some rules and one of them is to provide some of the work you have done to solve the exercise. I'm sure you have thought about that problem, it would be nice if you share those thoughts with us, so that we can help you better.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with 1 1 1 0? Sorry, I don't quite understand. I ask you one further thing: did you see the determinant of a matrix in your course of lineare algebra?
Also please consider reading [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) guide to learn how to tipe in mathjax. It would be more readable and will increase the chance that you will get an answer to your question. It is enough to put the symbols/numbers between to dollars $\$\text{symbol or number}\$$

Comment: sorry i edited the question

Comment: Again i still cannot understand your notation, but your solution is correct (if I understood it correctly), nice! For $t= \pm \frac15$ the set of vectors is dependent and thus it does not span $\Bbb{R}^3$, while if $t\neq \pm \frac15$, then you have a set of linearly independent vectors. Why exactly are you not sure of your solution?

Comment: I do not fully understand all the span-dependency thing, even though I know the definitions...  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: To that purpose i would like to give you [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/linear_combinations/v/linear-combinations-and-span) link. I think it really good explains the concept that you are looking for. Watch it carefully and I hope it helps. If you still have questions after viewing it, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks again! hope it helps!

Comment: I think that there is something missing from that $25t^2$ entry on the third row. At least it appears to me that you have done row operations affecting that entry.

Comment: @Ale: After Anna added her partly row reduced version of the matrix I think the downvotes stopped. I would be surprised if the question gets closed at this point. If it does (there are many automatons reviewing the queues), then flag us again. The issues you raised have been frequently discussed in Meta. Search for an appropriate thread, and add you bits, if you think you can add something that has not been said already.